# jQuery calculation inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i make a loop and add some values for the next iteration together like these in jQuery ?

```
var currLength = length;
for (var i = 1; i < dotCount -1; i++) {
  $("#myElement" + i).css("width", currLength);
  currLength += length + margin;
}
```

**Edit:
These is just an example. I just wanted to know how to use the .each function of jQuery because i had some different idea of usage. I doesn't make any difference in relation to a for loop**

Comment: Are you sure you want to be doing `+=`?

Comment: That's what your code does, though you're skipping the last `dotCount`, and you're always doubling the `currLength` before adding `margin`.

Comment: @Cole Johnson @ am not i am sorry correct it i add length to currLength

Comment: it should just be: currLength += margin;

Comment: I don't see any problem besides the one pointed by @CristiPufu (you were doubling currLength before adding the margin). I get what you are trying to do, but it would be better ussing a class for all "#myElement"+i elements, and use jQuery $.each function with the class

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
var currLength = length;
for (var i = 1; i < dotCount -1; i++) {
  $("#myElement" + i).css("width", currLength);
  currLength += margin;
}
```

`currLength` is set to the length already, right?

Answer (score 0):

These is the concrete scenario how i end up. Just need an idea of .each function, because i was thinking there is a way to merge these loops together.

```
        var bCurrLeft = left;
        $(this.backgroundElements).each(function()
        {
            $(this).animate(
                {
                    left: bCurrLeft,
                    top: top
                }, moveSpeed);
            bCurrLeft += singleWidth  + singleMargin;
        });
        var fCurrLeft = left;
        $(this.foregroundElements).each(function()
        {
            $(this).animate(
                {
                    left: fCurrLeft,
                    top: top
                }, moveSpeed);
            fCurrLeft += singleWidth  + singleMargin;
        });

        $(this.allElements).promise().done(callback);
```